# Scp with decreasing speed

Tags: scp

It has happened to me for years actually I'd say. I haven't tested too many use cases but whenever I've to copy by `scp` a large file to another machine (usually all of them running Ubuntu Server or Desktop, from 14.04 to 18.04, within a local network or to a remote location, from home, work, university, etc), the speed decreases with time. It starts, for example, at 2Mb/s, and then decreases second by second to reach even speeds as low as 100Kb/s.

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: i have a similar Problem, but the de facto limitor is the host where i copy from, if i use plain ftp or http it will not slow down, or if i use tar over netcat eben full speed